# mySQL date and time in separate columns - need to summarize rows by hour

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with two three columns (date, time and caller).  I need to know how many calls I received hourly, by day, to create a bar graph.  I am unfamiliar with combining date and time rows, to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am successfully summarizing call data (using above fields) by day, using the following query:

```
SELECT date(date) as date, count(*) AS count FROM call_details 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$date' AND '$date1' GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Well simply add a second group by and generate the HOUR value from the `time` column; `GROUP BY date, HOUR(\`time\`)`

Comment: If `date` is a DATE type then running a `date()` on it seems unnecessary. If `date` is a DATETIME type then running `date()` may make sense but then what is the `time` column for?